# ( if steatmetn), even if the value is null when I click the button it delete the items

Tags: javascript, if-statement

in the if statement, even if the value is null, when I click the button, it is still deleting the item which is in the array. I would be happy if you guys help, I have no idea.

[1]:

here is the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pm5K.png

Comment: That can happen when the value is an empty string. So, I recommend check if it isn't an empty string, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first screenshot - you need to remove comparison with null, I mean next:

```
if(dele){
   ....
} else {
   alert('Put a value');
}
```

Solution for the second screenshot:

```
function myfc2() {
  let change = document.getElementById("den").value;

  if(change){
    liste[change] = document.getElementById("sen").value;
  } else {
    alert("Put a value");
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = liste;
}
```